# Add data to end of a line in file C (without using second file)

Tags: c, file-handling

That's the file I have:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

And I want to add some character/string at the end of each line. I did some research but haven't found any solution that's not use an additional file. Here is what I came up with:

```
char c;
FILE *fp1 = fopen("Test.txt", "r+");
while ((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF){
    if (c == '\n'){
        fseek(fp1, -2, SEEK_CUR); // the '\n' is 2 bytes
        fputs("X\n", fp1);
        fseek(fp1, 1, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
```

It appends the string but deletes the first n characters of the newline (n - is a length of the string that I want to input). Output:

```
Line 1 X
ine 2 X
ine 3 X
```

Comment: Read the file into memory (into a big string if it's not binary), edit the *buffer*, reposition the file at the beginning and write. ... The regular way (read from a, edit, write to b) is very much easier. BTW: a [*filter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(software)) is basically just that: "read from `stdin`, edit, write to `stdout`"

Comment: The `X\n` is 3 bytes, so it overwrites the 2 byte `\n` and the first byte after the `\n` which is the first character of the next line

Comment: Note that using a buffer only works for a small file. When operating on big file you still have to write the output to a separate file

Comment: The perhaps not obvious point that the OP might not know, but all of the responses are taking for granted, is that it is not possible to add characters in the middle of a file — you can append, but the only way to make a change to the middle of a file is to rewrite the whole thing, or truncate it and then append.

Answer (score 0):

What program does sounds logical: you have a sequence of characters. Newline is just another caracter with its own code. So if you want to paste some text in the middle of that sequence - you need to move everything to the right as far as many characters you want to paste. In your case it's 1 character, I suppose. So you'd need to read everything after your newline, paste "X" and then newline and everything after it.